# Can the center of a hyperbolic line be inside the unit circle in the Poincare disc model?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the line intersecting two points inside the disc D. These points ($i/2$ and $1/2$) do not lie on a diameter, so I know they must lie on a Euclidean circle intersecting the disc. However, when I find the center of the corresponding circle in the upper half plane model H and then find the center in D (using the inverse of the mobius transform I used to transform D into H), I get my center as being inside the unit circle. All of the examples my professor has given us of hyperbolic lines in D have had their centers outside the disc. Have I screwed up or is it possible for the center to be within the disc so long as it is not entirely within the disc (as then it's a circle and not an H-line)?

Comment: Hint: Given a Euclidean circle $C$ defining a geodesic in $D$ consider the inversion in $C$. This inversion is an isometry of $D$. What is the image of the center of $C$ under the inversion?

Comment: the center of the image of a circle is not the image of the center of that circle.

Comment: That clears it up, thank you both very much!